# Highcharts update function not working properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am facing an issue using Highchart and it's update function.
When I update a chart with new modified options, sometime those modifications are not applied.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-update-issue?embed=1&file=index.js

The datalabels are set to allowOverlap: false when creating the chart, and then I update the chart with allowOverlap: true.
Yet the data labels are still using allowOverlap: false (can be seen on the second point)

I came across several issue for other highcarts options as well.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting it.

It seems like a regression. I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13449

As a temporary workaround try to update **series.dataLabels** options instead - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vshj95to/

```
chart.series[0].update({
    dataLabels: {
    allowOverlap: true
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for answering. This workaround will not work for me but thnaks you anyway ! I will check on the issue you reported !

Answer (score 0):

**Issue with update always "0"**

In case anyonoe came to this post looking for help on a issue using the "update" point, I thought I would mention a problem I ran into that was a simple fix but took hours to discover.

In my case I simply wanted to update the value

```
let curval=this.tiles[3].value = "24.9"
series3.points[0].update(curval);  <---- Will give "0" ... no error
```

For some reason a one decimal float value always updated to zero! What is interesting is that other updates with float values were working ok without the conversion? Anyway the fix was below:

```
let curval=parseFloat(this.tiles[3].value);
series3.points[0].update(curval);   <----- This works
```

Hope this may help someone else ...